# Raise an exception at import if conditions not met

Tags: python

I have a module that depends on some system settings. For example, to work properly it needs to have an environment variable FOO set. I would like the module to raise an Exception if this condition is not met at import time.

```
# mymodule.py
if 'FOO' not in sys.environ:
    raise SomeException('ensure that FOO is provided')
```

I would like to know:

1. Is it the best practice to check those conditions at import time, or maybe it would be better to do it later (when)
2. What type of exception should I raise? Should it be my own `class MyModuleImportError(Exception)` or maybe some built-in exceptions are more suitable and commonly used? One candidate would be [ImportError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ImportError), but it seems to be reserved for situation when python *"fails to find the module definition"*

Comment: This is kind of a strange thing to do in a module. In a script, sure (in which case I'd do it at the top of your "main code", whether that's in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block or not), but in a module, it's pretty odd. So… why do you want to do this?

Comment: But if you _do_ have a good reason for this, then yes, right near the top of your module is the best place to check—before executing any code that could have side effects.

Comment: Also, what exactly is "if 'FOO' not in sys.environ is None` supposed to mean? The `not in` expression will be either `True` or `False`, neither of which `is None`, so nothing of this form can ever be true. If you just want to check whether a key is in a collection or mapping, just use `not in`. If you want to check that it's in a mapping and not `None`, use `mapping.get(key) is not None`.

Comment: @abarnert, forget this `is None`, it was an unedited garbage

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
>>> import os
>>> if not os.getenv('FOO', False):
    raise OSError('FOO not in envs')
```

---

1. Yes, you should check these kind of things at the start of your code. Else there is no reason for it to continue running.
2. an [OSError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError) (as above)

Comment: OSError??  I boggle at that concept.  The problem is not really connected to the operating system, is it?

Comment: In case I don't know which exception to raise I often fall back on `raise NotImplementedError("Programmer did not care what to do in this case")`, because basically it is a case for which no handling is implemented, hence *that* exception.

Comment: Check [this PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/) for more on OSError vs IOError, and why they're sometimes (seemingly) interchangeable.

Comment: It seems the matter of "which error to raise" is subjective. So there is no "valid" answer. I think an OSError should be raised, since the environment is part of the operating system. If there was an "ENVERROR" I would raise that. But I also dislike creating new exceptions just for the hell of it. Regardless, of the error to be raised, this is the way to do it.